# Pass value of variables to another widget Flutter

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to pass a value of a variable from a StatefulWiget to another StatefulWidget

```
class InputFieldCheckTick extends StatefulWidget {
double timbreFiscaleFournisseur = 0.000;
bool exoTVA = false;
.
.
.
value: isTicked,
              onChanged: (value) async {
                await setState(() {
                  isTicked = value;
                  if (isTicked == false) {
                    widget.exoTVA = false;
                  } else {
                    widget.exoTVA = true;
                  }
                });
.
.
.
value: isTicked,
              onChanged: (value) async {
                await setState(() {
                  isTicked = value;
                  if (isTicked == false) {
                    widget.exoTVA = false;
                  } else {
                    widget.exoTVA = true;
                  }
                });
```

and i'm trying to pass the values of `exoTVA` and `timbreFiscaleFournisseur` here :

```
setState(() {
                                  future = ajoutFournisseur(
                                      numeroFournisseur.text,
                                      addressFournisseur.text,
                                      matriculeFiscaleFournisseur.text,
                                      raisonSocialeFournisseur.text,
                                      paysFournisseur.text,
                                      villeFournisseur.text,
                                      InputFieldCheckTick()
                                          .timbreFiscaleFournisseur,
                                      InputFieldCheckTick().exoTVA);
                                });
```

Comment: how you've used the second widget?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are creating an StatefulWidget which contains a `Final` property called `exoTVA`, something like:

```dart
class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
    final bool exoTVA;
    [...]
```

Because you are calling `widget.exoTVA` which refers to stateful related widget, and there is your mistake. You can't change `widget.exoTVA` for the way widgets are build. What you can do is to do this:

```dart
class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
    // Here you designate an instance value for your widget property
    bool? _exoTVA;
    // On initState you define from parent widget, I do this all the time
    @override
    initState((){
        super.initState();
        _exoTVA = widget.exoTVA;
    });
    [...] //Continue with the rest of your widget
```

Also when you call those changes in `setState`, change `widget.exoTVA` to `_exoTVA`, and to finish you can call that var like this:

```dart
setState(() {
                                  future = ajoutFournisseur(
                                      numeroFournisseur.text,
                                      addressFournisseur.text,
                                      matriculeFiscaleFournisseur.text,
                                      raisonSocialeFournisseur.text,
                                      paysFournisseur.text,
                                      villeFournisseur.text,
                                      InputFieldCheckTick()
                                          .timbreFiscaleFournisseur,
                                      _exoTVA);//Changed this line
                                });
```

For your reference, check out [StatefulWidget class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatefulWidget-class.html)